# How to handle many Api requests using Paging 3

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging

Following [this codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-paging#0) I have implemented pagination and caching using `RemoteMediator` (I am calling a simple API that returns a list of news). I am injecting this `RemoteMediator` to Repository which has method `getResultStream()` that returns `Flow<PagingData<News>>`. In ViewModel is function `getNews() : Flow<PagingData<News>>` and in Fragment I am calling this function and submitting list to RecyclerAdapter.

Now I want to add a new API call that returns news but with search keyword. What is the proper way to do it? Do I have to write all this code again and create a new `RemoteMediator`? The logic will be the same but now I have to pass a string argument to the Retrofit get function. The result of this call will replace items in RecyclerView, so I will have two sources of data but one Recycler, do I have to create also a `MediatorLiveData`? *(I don't add any code but if it help I can do it)*

---

One person asked how exactly I did it (Question posted as answer so it is deleted now but maybe it will help someone in future). So, in ViewModel I have this:

```kotlin
// this flow keeps query. If it is null it means that I want to get all News from API. If it is not null it means that I want to make another API request which takes a parameter query
private val _queryFlow: MutableStateFlow<String?> = MutableStateFlow(null)
val queryFlow: StateFlow<String?>
    get() = _queryFlow

// this function set and validate query
fun submitQuery(query: String?)
{
    Timber.d("Submit new search $query")
    _queryFlow.value = when
    {
        query.isNullOrEmpty() -> null
        query.trim()
            .isNotBlank() -> query.trim()
        else -> null
    }
}

// flow of paging data that I am using in RecyclerView
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
val homeNewsData = _queryFlow.flatMapLatest {
    searchNews(it)
}


private fun searchNews(
    query: String?
): Flow<PagingData<NewsRecyclerModel>>
{
    return newsRepository.getSearchResultStream(
        query
    )
        // mapping, filtering, separators etc.
        .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

NewsRepository has this function used in VM:

```kotlin
fun getSearchResultStream(searchKey: String?): Flow<PagingData<News>>
{
    val pagingSourceFactory = { database.cacheNewsDao.getNews() }
    return Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = NETWORK_PAGE_SIZE,
            enablePlaceholders = false,
            initialLoadSize = INITIAL_LOAD_SIZE
        ),
        remoteMediator = newsRemoteMediator.apply { this.searchKey = searchKey },
        pagingSourceFactory = pagingSourceFactory
    ).flow
}
```

NewsRemoteMedietor:

```kotlin
// it keeps submitted query. based on this I can letter define which API request I want to do
var searchKey: String? = null

override suspend fun load(loadType: LoadType, state: PagingState<Int, News>): MediatorResult
{
    \\ all logic the same like in codelabs

    try
    {
        val apiResponse =
            if (searchKey.isNullOrEmpty()) // query is null/empty get Trending news
                newsRetrofit.getTrending(
                    state.config.pageSize,
                    page * state.config.pageSize
                )
            else // query is not blank, make API request with search keyword
                newsRetrofit.getSearched(
                    state.config.pageSize,
                    page * state.config.pageSize,
                    searchKey!!
                )
        \\ again the same logic like in codelabs
    }
}
```

<sup>I don't know if it is the best way to do it (probably not) but in my case, it was working</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you still have one recyclerview, you can do something like:

```
val queryFlow = MutableStateFlow(startingQuery)
queryFlow.flatMapLatest { query ->
    Pager(..., MyRemoteMediator(query)) {
        MyPagingSource(...)
    }.flow
}
```